# Padding is invalid and cannot be removed. Padding Zeros works but ANSIX923, ISO10126 or PKCS7 do not

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, aes

Edit: [Here is a .NET fiddle of the issue](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xqkb2d)

I am currently trying to write a process which encrypts files sent in as streams of Byte. The AES library does not seem to be applying padding correctly.

When I try to do an encryption I get cipher bytes like this:

> ... 50 57 243 226 18 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ... (about 30,000 0s appended to the end)

When i think I should be getting cipher bytes like this (using PKCS7) :

> ... 50 57 243 226 18 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9

How do I get the actual padding method to be recognised and return padding like the PKCS7?

```
    Public Function Encrypt(InputStream As Stream) As Byte()

        Dim outputStream = New MemoryStream()

        Dim EncryptionKey As String = "MAKV2SPBNI99212"
        Using encryptor As Aes = Aes.Create()

            Dim pdb As New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, New Byte() {&H49, &H76, &H61, &H6E, &H20, &H4D, &H65, &H64, &H76, &H65, &H64, &H65, &H76})
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32)
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16)
            Using cs As New CryptoStream(outputStream, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                Dim data As Integer
                While (Assign(data, InputStream.ReadByte())) <> -1
                    cs.WriteByte(CByte(data))
                End While
            End Using
        End Using

        Return outputStream.GetBuffer()
    End Function

    Public Function Decrypt(InputStream As Stream) As Byte()

        Dim outputStream = New MemoryStream()

        Dim EncryptionKey As String = "MAKV2SPBNI99212"
        Using encryptor As Aes = Aes.Create()

            Dim pdb As New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, New Byte() {&H49, &H76, &H61, &H6E, &H20, &H4D, &H65, &H64, &H76, &H65, &H64, &H65, &H76})
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32)
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16)
            Using cs As New CryptoStream(InputStream, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read)
                Dim data As Integer
                While (Assign(data, cs.ReadByte())) <> -1
                    outputStream.WriteByte(CByte(data))
                End While
            End Using
        End Using

        Return outputStream.GetBuffer
    End Function

    Private Function Assign(Of T)(ByRef source As T, ByVal value As T) As T
        source = value
        Return value
    End Function
```

Comment: How do you know you should be getting that output?

Comment: Im just having a guess at what the output should look like, if I had a 16 byte block size, I would expect it to pad out like the example. But it is padding with about 30,000 zeros and none of the PKCS7 sequenced padding I have been reading about on wikipeida. The actual block size is coming out at &H00000080, I am not sure how many bytes that is. There is something fundamental i'm doing wrong with this AES library.

Comment: Does [CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.flushfinalblock?view=netcore-3.1) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using the `.GetBuffer` method on the returned MemoryStreams. `.GetBuffer` returns the underlying array which is typically larger than the amount of data in the Stream. That's why you are seeing the extra 0's at the end, and why the padding is failing to be read properly. See the remarks section in [the documentation for the MemoryStream.GetBuffer Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer?view=netframework-4.7.2)

What you should be doing instead is calling  `outputStream.ToArray` which will return a Byte array containing only the relevant data contained in the Stream, without all the trailing 0's.